# Filtering Website For Parental Control

Tags: php, networking, web, filtering

Anyone know how to filter website(like block some website) and the block is redirecting to some domain.

Example I block

```
porn.com and that redirect to test.com[My domain]
```

like in some hotspot. So the people in Local Network can't access that block content. I wanna it make for my office. So employee not open some site.

If there any requirement like router setting please tell me detail thank you.

Comment: In an Enterprise organisation there should be plenty of controls available to block content, on a smaller scale you should be able to block sites in the router. Failing that invest in some software that runs to prevent this sort of thing - perhaps even the anti-virus / firewall on client computers can be configured to assist. You could consider configuring DNS - perhaps use OpenDNS and use some of their controls

Comment: so that mean router is main for control it?there no option to redirect main website. or that need configure in some of windows file?we are small scale still grow.thank you for answer